# ¿Error Codeigniter, Como solucionarlo?

Tags: php, codeigniter, servidor, postgresql-9.3

Estoy usando `codeigniter` para desarrollar, el problema es que cuando ya tengo los archivos en el servidor me arroja el siguiente error...

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Home_model

Filename: /var/www/html/students/system/core/Loader.php

Line Number: 344

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/students/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 10
Function: model

File: /var/www/html/students/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Espero puedan colaborarme que no he podido solucionarlo, la app localmente funciona de maravilla.

Podria decir que depronto el problema sea de aca...

**CONTROLLER**

```
Class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->model('home_model');       
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
Class Home_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE); 
    }
```

Comment: Ya actualice la publicación espero que la pregunta sea para dar una solución...Saludos.

Comment: respuesta valida, pero esta podria ser la causa?

Comment: el problema a un persiste

Comment: A mi me sucedía algo similar y funciono agregando en mayúscula la primera letra del Modelo.$this->load->model('Home_model');

Comment: Hola @AlfonsoCarrasco, tengo una duda, posiblemente lo que me dices funcione porque ya consulte una parte en ingles pero mi duda es, si tengo muchos modelos les cambio la primera por mayusacula? si en mi controlador tengo una funcion como la siguiente :: $answer = $this->home_model->login(); deberia de poner el home_model en mayuscula? en todas las funciones?

Comment: Hola! En que carpeta se encuentra el archivo home_model.php?

Comment: en la carpeta models

Comment: Daniel, tengo entendido que ya sean controlador o modelo la primera es en mayúsculas

Comment: ok, pero eso tambien se aplica a la funciones?

Comment: no, solo en las Clases y cuando accedes a los controlares y modelos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He observado según el código que muestras, que estás desarrollando en Linux...

En ese caso, cuando haces la carga del modelo de Codeigniter, debes tener en cuenta que Linux es "case sensitive" y para el sistema la instrucción

`$this->load->model('home_model');`

será distinta de la instrucción

`$this->load->model('Home_model');`.

Comprueba el nombre del fichero PHP del home_model (mayúsculas o minúsculas)

Creo que tu problema puede venir por ahí.

Saludos